# Rerun DAG manually for previous date

Tags: airflow

I'm still learning Apache Airflow. I'm kind of confused about loading data of specific date. I have look up to some articles but has not found reference to do this yet. Let's say I have this below DAG. I run it daily and I want to load data of D-1 of current date. Should I specify it inside the SQL? like `WHERE order_date = today-1`?

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, "/db-config")
import dbconfig
import datetime
import logging 
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator 
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

def report_sales_summary():

    credential = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file("/db-config")
    project_id = dbconfig.project
    client = bigquery.Client(credentials= credential,project=project_id)

    query = client.query("""
        INSERT INTO `{}.{}.{}`
        WITH 
        BASE AS (
        SELECT *,
        EXTRACT(DATE FROM (TIMESTAMP(PARSE_DATETIME("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M" , order_created_date),'Asia'))) order_date   
        FROM `{}.{}.{}`
        WHERE 
        order_status = 'sale'
        ),
        A AS (
        SELECT
        order_date,
        COUNT(customer) total_customer,
        SUM(CAST(unit_price AS FLOAT64)) total_price
        FROM BASE
        GROUP BY order_date
        ),
        B AS (
        SELECT 
        order_date,
        order_type product_category,
        COUNT(product_sku) total_qty
        FROM BASE
        GROUP BY order_date,product_category
        )
        SELECT A.order_date, total_customer, product_category, total_qty, total_price 
        FROM A JOIN B ON A.order_date = B.order_date
        WHERE A.order_date = {}
    """).format(dbconfig.project, dbconfig.source_dataset, dbconfig.source_table,
                dbconfig.target_dataset, dbconfig.target_table, {{execution_date}})

default_dag_args = {
    'owner' : 'intrepid',
    'depends_on_past' : False,
    'start_date' : days_ago(1)
}

sales_summary_dag = DAG(
    'report_sales_summary_dag',
    default_args = default_dag_args,
    schedule_interval= @daily,
    catchup = False
)

report_sales_summary = PythonOperator(
    task_id = 'report sales summary',
    python_callable = report_sales_summary
)

report_sales_summary
```

Comment: Do you mean yesterday date or prev execution date? The diff is that if your dag for some reason didnt run so prev execution will give you the last run (idempotent) and yesterday not

Comment: sorry, yesterday date

Comment: yes, as you suggested unless you are having any issue with it.

Comment: I made little edit in the code. Sorry, I want to clarify my understanding. With the `WHERE order_date = {execution_date}` when running daily, the `order_date` will automatically filled with `start_date` which is `days_ago(1)` and if there's a manual rerun with `airflow dags backfill --start-date START_DATE --end-date END_DATE dag_id` the `order_date` will filled with the date params passed in the command. Is it correct? That is want I want to achieve in my code

Comment: yes, but the way you implement the jinja template is wrong. you can not do it inside the task only in the dag or get it from the task instance (see my answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The execution date can get from the context of the task.

in case you would like to get it inside the the callable python you need to add parameter to the function as (see example):

```
def report_sales_summary(execution_date): # type pendulum.datetime.DateTime.

    credential = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file("/db-config")
    project_id = dbconfig.project
    client = bigquery.Client(credentials= credential,project=project_id)

    query = client.query("""
    INSERT INTO `{}.{}.{}`
    WITH 
    BASE AS (
    SELECT *,
    EXTRACT(DATE FROM (TIMESTAMP(PARSE_DATETIME("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M" , order_created_date),'Asia'))) order_date   
    FROM `{}.{}.{}`
    WHERE 
    order_status = 'sale'
    ),
    A AS (
    SELECT
    order_date,
    COUNT(customer) total_customer,
    SUM(CAST(unit_price AS FLOAT64)) total_price
    FROM BASE
    GROUP BY order_date
    ),
    B AS (
    SELECT 
    order_date,
    order_type product_category,
    COUNT(product_sku) total_qty
    FROM BASE
    GROUP BY order_date,product_category
    )
    SELECT A.order_date, total_customer, product_category, total_qty, total_price 
    FROM A JOIN B ON A.order_date = B.order_date
    WHERE A.order_date = {}
""").format(dbconfig.project, dbconfig.source_dataset, dbconfig.source_table,
            dbconfig.target_dataset, dbconfig.target_table, execution_date)
```